# Value not display into multiple picker view

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm making an app with a viewcontroller that displays two arrays in two different pickerview, an array has the values ​​saved within the application the others are retrieved with rest calls from a rest server. I tried to print the values ​​of the rest server and they are displayed but they are not displayed inside the uipickerview how can I solve this? what is due

```
class ModificaArticoloMagazzino: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
{

    private var TipologiaUIPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    private var MagazzinoModUIPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()
    private let valori = ["Carico","Scarico","Rimozione","Spostamento"]
    private var SetValue:String="Carico"
    private var filteredDataMagazzini: [MagazzinoStruct] = []

    init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        //Caricamento Magazzini
       //Caricamento Magazzini
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let mtemp = Magazzino(User: self.u)
        mtemp.CaricaMagazzini(completion: { result in

                self.filteredDataMagazzini=result
                print("\n \n Magazzini caricati: \(result.count)")
            //Configurazione Picker View Tipologia Preventivo
            self.labelMagazzinoMod = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 400, width: 120, height: 21))
            self.labelMagazzinoMod.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
            self.labelMagazzinoMod.text = "Magazzino: "
            self.view.addSubview(self.labelMagazzinoMod)
            self.MagazzinoModUIPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 400, width: 200, height: 50))
            self.MagazzinoModUIPicker.delegate = self
            self.MagazzinoModUIPicker.dataSource = self
            self.MagazzinoModUIPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            self.view.addSubview(self.MagazzinoModUIPicker)

        });
    }

        //Configurazione Picker View Tipologia Preventivo
        labelTipologia = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 270, width: 120, height: 21))
        labelTipologia.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
        labelTipologia.text = "Tipologia: "
        self.view.addSubview(labelTipologia)
        self.TipologiaUIPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: (self.view.frame.width / 2) - 70, y: 270, width: 200, height: 50))
        self.TipologiaUIPicker.delegate = self as UIPickerViewDelegate
        self.TipologiaUIPicker.dataSource = self as UIPickerViewDataSource
        self.TipologiaUIPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.view.addSubview(TipologiaUIPicker)
        //Quantita--> labelQuantitaMod e txtQuantita
        labelQuantitaMod = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 220, width: 60, height: 21))
        labelQuantitaMod.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16.0)
        labelQuantitaMod.text = "Quantita: "
        self.view.addSubview(labelQuantitaMod)
        txtQuantita = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 120, y: 220, width: 200, height: 21));
        txtQuantita.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        txtQuantita.text = "1"
        self.view.addSubview(txtQuantita)


    }

    //Funzione per aggiornare articolo in magazzino
    @objc func AggiornaArticoloMagazzino(sender: UIButton!) {
         let mtemp = Magazzino(SetArticolo: art, User: u)

        if(SetValue=="Carico" || SetValue=="Scarico" || SetValue=="Rimozione"){

            mtemp.Aggiorna(Quantita: Int(txtQuantita.text!)!, QuantitaPrecedente: art.Quantita!, IdMagazzino2: 0,Modalita:SetValue, completion: { result in

                 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
                    if(result==false){
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "\(self.SetValue) non riuscito ", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    else{
                        if(self.SetValue=="Rimozione"){
                            self.previosScreen()
                        }
                        else if(self.SetValue=="Scarico"){
                            self.art.Quantita=self.art.Quantita!-Int(self.txtQuantita.text!)!
                        }
                        else if(self.SetValue=="Carico"){
                            self.art.Quantita=self.art.Quantita!+Int(self.txtQuantita.text!)!
                        }
                        self.labelQuantita.text = "Quantita attuale: \(String(describing: self.art.Quantita!))"
                    }
                 });
            });
        }
        else{

            mtemp.Aggiorna(Quantita: Int(txtQuantita.text!)!, QuantitaPrecedente: art.Quantita!, IdMagazzino2: 0,Modalita:SetValue, completion: { result in

                 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
                    if(result==false){
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: "\(self.SetValue) non riuscito ", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                 });
            });
        }

    }

    //Questa funzione verifica quale selezione viene effettuata
    func CheckSelezione(row: Int){

        if(valori[row]=="Carico"){

            txtQuantita.isEnabled = true
            txtQuantita.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else if(valori[row]=="Scarico"){
            txtQuantita.isEnabled = true
            txtQuantita.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

        else if(valori[row]=="Rimozione"){
            txtQuantita.isEnabled = false
            txtQuantita.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
        else{
            txtQuantita.isEnabled = true
            txtQuantita.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        }

        SetValue=valori[row]
    }



    //Funzione per tornare alla schermata principale

    func previosScreen(){
        let returnView = TabBarViewController()
        self.present(returnView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @objc func Return(sender: UIButton!) {
        previosScreen()
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView ==  TipologiaUIPicker {
           return valori.count
        }
        else{
             return filteredDataMagazzini.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView ==  TipologiaUIPicker {
         CheckSelezione(row: row)
        return valori[row]
        }
        else{
             print("\n Nome Magazzino\(filteredDataMagazzini[row].Nome!)")
           return  filteredDataMagazzini[row].Nome
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't post the whole code. only post the code which is relevant to your question.

Comment: @Dharmesh i have remove unused code

Comment: Which pickerview data is not showing?

Comment: MagazzinoModUIPicker not show data @Dharmesh

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check result in your `API` call like how you are getting the data from server. next step is you need to cast your data object into `MagazzinoStruct` object then you need to append that object into your `filteredDataMagazzini` array.

Now once you do that you need to reload your `MagazzinoModUIPicker` pickerview once you complete the first task.

And you need to reload `MagazzinoModUIPicker` in main queue because you are making an `asynchronous` call with `API`.

Comment: its an `asynchronous` call means data coming from server. So you need to wait until its complete.

Comment: but I only like it with this code in other views it doesn't happen

Comment: Can you share demo project where I can check if you are missing something?